# append() text value to div onclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an instant messenger using jquery and am having trouble taking the message typed into the message field after clicking the "send" button

I have the html

```
<body>
    <div class="main-window">
    <div class="chat-screen"></div>
        <div class="bottom-wrapper">
            <input class="text-bar"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Send"class="send-btn">Send</input>
        </div>
    </div>                
<body>
```

and I have tried to append it using this jquery

```
$('.send-btn').click(function() {
    $(".text-bar").text().appendTo(".chat-screen");
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K95P3/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

change

```
$(".text-bar").text()
```

to

```
$(".text-bar").val()
```

---

you code becomes
[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/K95P3/7/)

use  [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('.send-btn').click(function () {
    $(".chat-screen").append($(".text-bar").val());
});
```

---

Clear Textbox and new chat in new line.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chat_screen = $(".chat-screen");
    var text_bar = $(".text-bar")
    $('.send-btn').click(function () {
        chat_screen.append(text_bar.val() + '<br/>');
        text_bar.val('');
    });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6ELMb/)

Comment: It works, thanks. How would I then clear the input box after the message is sent? @Tushar Gupta

Comment: $('.text-bar').val('');

Comment: @sMilbz `$(".text-bar").val('');`

Comment: Thanks. How would I get the next message to be on a new line @Praveen

Comment: How would I send the message using return key? @Praveen

Comment: @sMilbz better ask a new question  .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $('.send-btn').click(function(){
    $('.chat-screen').append($(".text-bar").val());
    });
```

Comment: Still no luck. The value hasn't even changed in firebug @MaheshMajeti

Answer (score 0):

The `.text()` (and correct `.val()`) functions return strings, not jQuery objects, and therefore don't have the `appendTo()` function available on them. You'll need to do this instead:

```
$('.chat-screen').append($('.text-bar').val());
```

Also make sure that, if the script is in the `<head>` of your HTML page, or comes before the actual HTML of the elements, you wrap it in a DOM ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.send-btn').click(function(){
        $('.chat-screen').append($('.text-bar').val());
    });
});
```

And, of course, check that jQuery is being loaded correctly (it wasn't in your jsFiddle at all).

Since this is going to (probably) be running a lot of times, you'd want to cache the selectors for the chat screen and the text input, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $chatscreen = $('.chat-screen'),
        $textbar = $('.text-bar');
    $('.send-btn').click(function(){
        $chatscreen.append($textbar.val());
        $textbar.val('');
    });
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K95P3/21/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is you fiddle updates: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K95P3/13/)

Use `val()` instead `text()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.send-btn').click(function(){
//$(".text-bar").val().appendTo(".chat-screen");
$(".chat-screen").append($(".text-bar").val())
$(".chat-screen").append('<br />')
});
```

please see http://jsfiddle.net/K95P3/15/

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. Add space between `value` and `class` attributes in input
2. Change `.text()` to `.val()` - inputs don't have text nodes, just values
3. Use `$('.chat-screen').append($(".text-bar").val());`
4. Make sure you have jQuery included

See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K95P3/11/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you really should append an html tag, not just text. I mean, you could, but shouldn't.

What i would recommend is this:

Create a base container for a message like:

```
       <div class="message-container" style="display:none;"> 
          <span class="message"> </span>
       </div>
```

You then clone this container, stuff it the value of the input in the chat and append it to the chat screen.
The code could be something like:

```
      $('.send-btn').click(function(){
               var container = $('.message-container:hidden').clone(true).show();
               container.find('.message').text($(".text-bar").val());
               container.appendTo($('.chat-screen'));
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Append text and dropdown value sametime

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
//var x=$("#cars option:selected").text();
//var y=$("#bus").val();
//alert(''+x+'     '+y+'');
$(".chat-screen2").append($("#cars").val()+'<br/>');
 $(".chat-screen").append($("#bus").val()+'<br/>');
 $("#bus").val('');
 });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>


  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input id="bus" type="text">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <br><br>
  <div class="chat-screen2" style="float:left;"></div>
  <div class="chat-screen" style="float:left;margin-left:10px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```